# ASP.NET LINQ Error Cannot create a query result of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dictionary

I am trying to create a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` through a Linq statement

It gives me the following **error:** Cannot create a query result of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'

```
        var output = (
                    from e in EDC.Energideklarationer_As
                    where MunicipalityName.Contains(e.Municipality)
                    group e by e.Municipality into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Municipality = g.Key,

                        listan = new List<int>()
                        {
                        g.Count(e => e.H== "El"),
                        g.Count(e => e.H== "Eldningsolja"),
                        g.Count(e => e.H== "Flis"),
                        g.Count(e => e.H== "Markvarmepump"),
                        g.Count(e => e.H== "Ved")
                        }
                    }
            ).ToDictionary(x => x.Municipality, x=> x.listan);
```

Comment: Can you try split the `select` and the `ToDictionary()` into 2 lines and let us know if error still occurs? And if so, please let us know which line is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure what you mean though. Can you show me an example?

Comment: `var temp = from e in...`, then `var output = temp.ToDictionary(x => x.Municipality, x=> x.listan);` this way we can know which part of your linq is really triggering the issue.

Comment: It is complaining at the .ToDictionary() 

With the same error: 
Cannot create a query result of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: Is `EDC.Energideklarationer_As` happens to be an `IQueryable`

Comment: I'll have to check once I have access to the files again on Monday.
If it is an IQueryable, would that explain the error?

Comment: @user3782642 Yes I would imagine that is the case. You could refactor the anonymous type into a typed class with properties for each of the `count`s on the grouping and then have an extra property to return a list with each of those to get around this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using some kind of ORM library and the `EDC.Energideklarationer_As` object is an `IQueryable` implemented in that ORM. What happens is that this library is trying to generate a query (maybe SQL query, depending on what library you're using) to the underlying data source from your LINQ query.

Some expressions are not supported in some ORMs - for example Entity Framework won't handle `select new int[] { ... }`, but will handle `select new List<int> { ... }`. It seems that the library you're using does not support creating new List in a query. And the exception is thrown in `ToDictionary`, because that's where the result is instantiated and LINQ gets translated.

Try replacing the list:

```
                listan = new List<int>()
                {
                    g.Count(e => e.H== "El"),
                    g.Count(e => e.H== "Eldningsolja"),
                    g.Count(e => e.H== "Flis"),
                    g.Count(e => e.H== "Markvarmepump"),
                    g.Count(e => e.H== "Ved")
                }
```

with another anonymous type:

```
                listan = new 
                {
                    El = g.Count(e => e.H== "El"),
                    Eldningsolja = g.Count(e => e.H== "Eldningsolja"),
                    Flis = g.Count(e => e.H== "Flis"),
                    Markvarmepump = g.Count(e => e.H== "Markvarmepump"),
                    Ved = g.Count(e => e.H== "Ved")
                }
```